# Java - JList Clicking

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a `JList` with a `JScrollPane`. If I only have one thing in the `JList`, there will be empty space due to the `JScrollPane`. If I click anywhere in the `JList`, it will click the one element. Is there a way to make it only click the element if I actually click it? Also, I am using a custom renderer for the `JList` to add images, if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the index that was clicked via [`locationToIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#locationToIndex%28java.awt.Point%29).

> Returns the cell index closest to the given location in the list's
>   coordinate system. To determine if the cell actually contains the
>   specified location, compare the point against the cell's bounds, as
>   provided by `getCellBounds`. This method returns `-1` if the model is
>   empty.

Comment: @JonMannerberg, This will allow you to filter the selection and determine whether or not the selection is "legal".

Comment: The `locationToIndex` always returns > -1 when there is at least one element in the `JList`.

Answer (score 3):

This could help you.

```
public class JListOperations extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jsp = null;
    private javax.swing.JList<java.lang.String> jl = null;
    public JListOperations(){
        super();    
    }
    public void initialiseComponents(){
        jl = new javax.swing.JList<java.lang.String>(new java.lang.String[]{"Item 1"});
        /*
         * Add mouse listener which checks if the mouse click point is on the item. If not deselect the item  
         */
        jl.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent mouseEvent){
                if (!jl.getCellBounds(jl.getSelectedIndex(), jl.getSelectedIndex()).contains(mouseEvent.getPoint())){
                    jl.removeSelectionInterval(jl.getSelectedIndex(), jl.getSelectedIndex());
                }
                java.lang.System.out.println(jl.getSelectedIndex());
            }
        });
        jsp = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(jl);
        getContentPane().add(jsp);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(java.lang.String args[]){
        JListOperations jlopFrame = new JListOperations();
        jlopFrame.initialiseComponents();
        jlopFrame.pack();
        jlopFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fits your case but you can try `List.isFileList` property:

```
list.putClientProperty("List.isFileList", Boolean.TRUE);
```

This will force ListUI to make sure that the point is within the actual bounds of a list item(see [SwingUtilities2.loc2IndexFileList](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/swing/sun/swing/SwingUtilities2.java.htm)).

However, setting this property may change the look and feel of your list.